# How to lock the toolbars in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, menubar

I'm new to JetBrains WebStorm IDE.  I really like it, especially for my JavaScript development, but I can't find how to set a very simple preference.  I use the Project and Structure toolbars constantly, but every time one of the toolbars loses focus, the toolbar hides.  Is there any way to lock the toolbars to keep them from hiding so that they are always visible?  It seems like something very obvious, but perhaps not...  I have gone through every setting in preferences that I can see but haven't found anything that works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the **Pinned Mode**:

[image: pinned mode]

If you also enable **Split Mode**, you can have both `Project` and `Structure` visible at the same time on the same side.

Comment: It worked!  Thank you for the quick response.  I tried a number of combinations of those modes, but I must have not had pinned and docked selected... but thank you for your help!